# Problem about convergence of an integral

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, measurable-functions, sequence-of-function

Assume that we have a sequence $f_k \in L^1{(\Bbb R^n)}$ pointwise converging to $f$ such that

1. $\left|f_k\right|$ converges pointwise and monotonically to $\left| f \right|$
2. The limit $\lim_k\int_{\Bbb R^n} f_k$ exists finite

Can we conclude that $f$ is in $L^1{(\Bbb R^n)}$? Or, at least, can we say something about the equality $\lim_k \int f_k = \int f$? I have no idea how to do this, thanks in advance to everyone that is willing to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_k(x)=x$ for $|x| \leq k$ and $0$ for $|x| >k$. Let $f(x)=x$ for all $x$. Then your hypothesis is satisfied (with $\int f_k=0$ for all $k$)  but $f$ is not integrable.

Comment: oh yes, it's true, thanks. Is there some hypothesis that would make it work? Different from the usual ones, like dominated convergence eccetera

Comment: If $\sup_k \int |f_k| <\infty$ then Fatou's Lemma tells you that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: Conversely if $|f_k|$ increases to $|f|$ and $f$ is integrable then $\sup_k \int |f_k| <\infty$. @astrobarrel